# "Access Denied!" after I changed root password

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm new in the phpMyAdmin stuff. I tried to change my wordpress password and I managed to edit my root (localhost) password.  I presently can't access my wordpress, phpMyAdmin!

I tried multiple things but things like `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'rCZ4Xnz78zbLY2Vh';` cant be found in any folders.

I use xampp with phpMyAdmin. In my htdocs folder, I have a folder called "phpmyadmin" and "wordpress".

Comment: This is one of those reasons why you shouldn't be using the `root` account for things like WordPress. Can you find the old password anywhere in either of these directories? Don't forget you can use [MySQL Workbench](http://mysqlworkbench.org) to fix mistakes like this.

Comment: Here is the mysql reset root password http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: If you have control over your MySQL database, you can just restart it without requiring passwords, and you can reset the `root` password.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reset the root password?

```
Run C:\xampp\mysql\resetroot.bat
```

This should reset all your root and phpmyadmin passwords.

Comment: Access is denied.
Access is denied.
Access is denied.
Access is denied.
Access is denied.
The system cannot find the file specified.
Could Not Find C:\WINDOWS\System32\resetroot.sql

Passwoerter fuer Benutzer "root" und "pma" wurden geloescht.
Passwords for user "root" and "pma" were deleted.

Press any key to continue . . .



this is what i get

Comment: Did you run it by navigating to C:\xampp\mysql and then running resetroot.bat? If you succeeded in resetting the passwords, phpmyadmin should be open now